# A group generated by two elements such that its product with itself is not generated by two elements.

Tags: group-theory

We have $S_5=\langle (12345), (12)\rangle$ and we can show that $S_5\times S_5$ is also generated by two elements. Is there a group $G$ generated by two elements such that $G\times G$ is not generated by two elements?

Comment: Just keep iterating this. Define $G=S_5 \times S_5$. etc.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest example is $G=C_2 \times C_2$ which is generated by 2 elements, but $G\times G = C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$ cannot be generated by fewer than 4 elements. Similar things work with any non-cyclic $p$-group.

Comment: If $G$ is solvable and $G/[G,G]$ is cyclic, must $G \times G$ be generated by 2 elements?  If true, probably a result of Wielandt or Gaschütz, but I suspect it is not true. (If $G/[G,G]$ is not cyclic, then clearly $G \times G$ cannot be generated by two elements; the converse holds for solvable $G$ up to order 200.)